# Broken shadow render blender

Tags: rendering

I render my sim ripper from the sims 4, then I put it into the blender, I use a sunlight, and when I see the results of the render, the shaadow is broken, ugly. it's been almost 1 year I don't know how to fix it, I hope you can help me, thank you

[image]

---

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/kdeyXJqk/

this link, i upload file blend

Comment: Please attach blend file

Comment: @NascentSpace *If* a blend file is required, it is important to explain *where* to upload it, i.e. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=kdeyXJqk" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/kdeyXJqk/)

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem with smooth-shaded, low-polygon-count models. It is caused by mismatching of the true shape of the polygonal model and the smoothed normals.

Here are three solutions:

**1. Soften the lighting.**

Increasing the size of the light will:

✔ Preserve the polygon count.
✔ Preserve the shader realism.
✖ Alter the look of the render.

**2. Adjust the shadow termination.***

Adjusting the shadow termination offset will:

✔ Preserve the polygon count.
✖ Alter the shader realism.
✔ Preserve the look of the render.

**3. Subdivide the geometry.**

Subdividing the geometry will:

✖ Alter the polygon count.
✔ Preserve the shader realism.
✔ Preserve the look of the render.

** Blender 2.9+ Cycles only*

Comment: do you have video tutorial?

Comment: @RafiAkmal I don't. I can tell you that the shadow termination setting is in the object tab in the latest builds when using Cycles to render.

Comment: can you give me screenshoot? i usee blender 2.82

Comment: @RafiAkmal You must download version 2.90 or later to have the feature. There is a video that covers this now. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Vq_i7KqQlI&t=124s (video uploaded Aug 7)