# How to get rid of sharp edges\artifacts in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edges, normals, artifacts

So I imported a model of my sim into blender to mess around with renders and maybe try and make some CC, but (as usually the case with game extracted models) the model has these 'artifacts':

[image]

How do I get rid of them? I removed doubles, reset vectors and recalculated normals, cleared sharps, have 2 light sources with a plane underneath to bounce light off of, idk what else to do...
Edit: Subdivision surface doesn't fix it, and on the other model I imported smooth shading doesn't work at all

Sims likes to use overlapping geometry for things like beards and hair and upon removing doubles the polygons still look messed up. I remember there might be double polygons sometimes but I don't remember how to clean them. This one shows only with subsurf [image]

And random walk subsurf for some reason looks like this (after removing doubles)[image]

Ok, I see why the second model is messed up now
[image]

The first one looks alright though, must be something else...

The proposed answer was wrong, I mentioned I checked the normals and then someone proposes to check the normals and closes the question.

[image]

Comment: Is your texture mapped to the correct UV map?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct one

Comment: try Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals?

Comment: Made it worse O_o

Comment: Looks like a seam. Is the Color Space value of the normal image texture set to Non-Color?

Comment: The skin doesn't have normal maps, only clothing (sometimes).

Comment: Nope :D They're all the right way out

Comment: This question seems to be a combination of about three-ish separate problems. Here is an answer to one of them: [Broken shadow render blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/190050/66773)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inaccurate shading on object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165080/inaccurate-shading-on-object)

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat of the same issue and my model looked like this:
[image]

I fixed it by:

1. going into edit mode
2. selecting all faces
3. pressing ALT+N and selecting "Recalculate Outside":
   [image: Select Recalculate Outside]

After that, my problem was fixed:
[image]

I hope I could help anyone, even though this question is 1.5 years old.